# Import Javascript library globally via Webpack

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, webpack

I am trying to remove script tags for javascript libraries from my html, and so have removed underscore.js from a template page.

To replace this, within my index.js (webpack entry point), I have the following

```
import 'underscore';
```

The size of the webpack outputted bundle.js file increases by 50k when I do this, so I know that the library is in bundle.js.  However, underscore is not available when I try to use it in the console on a page which has the bundle.js included.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const precss = require('precss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const postcssImport = require('postcss-import');

module.exports = {

  context: __dirname + '/frontend',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, './static'),
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
    { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/, query: { presets: ['es2015'] } },
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap&importLoaders=1!postcss') },
    ],
  },
  vendor: [
    'underscore',
  ],
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('si-styles.css'),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      underscore: 'underscore',
    }),
  ],
  postcss: function(webpack) {
    return [
      postcssImport({ addDependencyTo: webpack }), // Must be first item in list
      precss,
      autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }),
    ];
  },

};
```

Comment: You can't call `_`, even though you've imported it in one of your modules, because modules system like the ES6 `import` statement are designed to avoid polluting the global space. Something would need to assign that module to the global scope or global object (`window`) in order for you to get a reference to it and use it outside of one of your modules where you imported it. See [the WebPack docs for how to get WebPack to do this for you for any module](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to achieve that you can use this webpack plugin:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    underscore: "underscore"
})
```

by the way it is not necessary that you import the library in the index file of your directory. You will have access to the library also specifying a new entry point in your webpack config file.. You could then put all your vendor code in a vendor.js boundle like so:

```
entry: {
    main: [
        './app/js/main.js'
    ],
    vendor: [
            'underscore',
            'lodash',
            'my-awesome-library!'
        ]
  }
```

UPDATE: There is a very good tutorial in how to use webpack in production on egghead.io.. Try to [check it out](https://egghead.io/courses/using-webpack-for-production-javascript-applications)!

Comment: Thank you very much, that has worked!  Are you able to explain why although it was getting included in bundle.js, it wasn't available to be used?

Comment: Thank you for the update - i'm afraid i have lost you though.  I have removed the import form my index.js as suggested, and added an array fro vendor to my webpack.  However it no longer works... I will update my original question with my webpack config

Comment: Let me check that I didn't give you a bad advice on the second part (remove the import) It is working for me, but I didn't investigate enaugh...

For what concerns your first question I think that it has to do with the way that webpack uses to rename all the modules that are imported. You should try to put a breakpoint in your code and see using the console which are the variables name...
I hope that helps..